# Lagrange Multiplier - Confusion , Bishop -PRML

Tags: calculus, machine-learning, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to solve Excercise 4.4 of the book  Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop . Implicitly we need to show that if we  :
Maximize : $$w^{T}(m_{2}-m_{1})  \tag{1}\label{1}  $$
Subject to  : $$w^{T}w=  \tag{2}\label{2}  1$$ 
Then the optimal value for $w$ we obtain is of the form $$w \propto (m_{2}-m_{1})$$
My Approach :
I started with lagrangian which is   :

\begin{align}
L=w^{T}(m_{2}-m_{1}) + \lambda(w^{T}w-1)  \tag{3}\label{3}        
\end{align}

Where $\lambda$ is the Lagrangian Multiplier.
From this , I get :
\begin{align}
 \nabla_{w}L =(m_{2}-m_{1}) + 2\lambda w  =0  \\
=> w = - \frac{m_{2}-m_{1}}{2 \lambda}  \tag{4}\label{4}      
\end{align}
In the official solution here is where the author concludes the solution and writes ,"it follows that  $w \propto (m_{2}-m_{1})$ . If i however try to see  what lambda looks like , i substitute the value of $w$ in the constraint equation $Eq.2$ to get:
\begin{align}
\frac{(m_{2}-m_{1})^{T} (m_{2}-m_{1})}{4 \lambda^{2}} = 1\\
=>\lambda =  \frac{|m_{2}-m_{1}|}{2} \tag{5}\label{5}      
\end{align}
Now if i substitue for $\lambda$ to in $Eq. 4$ i get
\begin{align}
w = -\frac{m_{2}-m_{1}}{|m_{2}-m_{1}|} \\
=> \frac{w}{m_{2}-m_{1}} = -\frac{1}{|m_{2}-m_{1}|}
\end{align}

which does not establish direct proportionality between $w$ and $m_{2}-m_{1}$ as $-\frac{1}{|m_{2}-m_{1}|}$ is not constant.
Edit2 : The reason  why $|m_{2}-m_{1}|$ is not constant  is because $m_{1}$(and for that matter $m_{2}$) would change as new points are classified to the classes $C_{1}$ or $C_{2}$

So where my interpretation or mathematics is going wrong ?

Comment: I think the mistake is at $(5)$, the $|\cdot|^{0.5}$ need to be only $|\cdot|$ and then you get when substitute to $w$ that its just the depend on the normalised $m_{2}-m_{1}$. which is indeed proportional to the difference

Comment: I corrected that error , and if we interpret the answer now, we can say that $w  = (m_{2}-m_{1})/|(m_{2}-m_{1})|$ which is the unit vector in the direction of $(m_{2}-m_{1})$ . So now we say $w$ which is the unit vector is proportional to ...what ?

Comment: $m_{1},m_{2}$ are only the means of the data, so they are given per data (as stated in page 187 in PRML) so it does a constant, so the proportion is valid. isn't it?

Comment: Well , it is constant at a particular time stamp. It changes as new points are classified to , lets say class $C_{1}$ . In that case $m_{1}$ which is the mean of the the points classified as $C_{1}$ would change.